# How to expand and collapse the fields within the layout

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-animation

I have multiple EditText fields in a LinearLayout. One of the EditText is for heading. There can be multiple inputs for other EditText fields. What I need is when user presses the OK Buttons all other Edittext fields should be merged within the Heading field and only Heading should appear on the screen. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this or at least how to start this?